# Unable to access to my bridge router settings page

Tags: wds

I have two routers, A and B, I made B work as AP to extend the wireless internet coverage, by connecting A and B with LAN to LAN connection, and enabled WDS in each of them, and made them to work in the same channel, and it worked!

Now they have the same IP, and different SSID names, and when I try to enter the router's B settings page (`192.168.1.1`) it redirect me to router's A page (because they're the same network). How can I access to the router's B settings page? To edit SSID name, Of course without interpreting the connection between them.

Router B is working in mode "WDS+Root". And I've indeed connected the B router to a PC, the internet is working, but I can't access to the B router's settings page also, it redirects me to A's page.

Comment: Connect it temporarily directly to a pc, then access the firmware.

Comment: Why do you want to edit the SSID?  That would defeat the entire purpose of putting the device in Bridge Mode.

Comment: I've edited the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To work in "bridge mode" use a bridge port. The LAN port introduces NAT and a boatload of issues you don't want. Connect a regular bridge port on one to a bridge port on the other.
2. Now that both devices are in the same network segment they need to have different IPs within the same subnet. Whichever device you can log in to, change the IP on that one to something that you know is outside the DHCP scope and not conflicting with any other device.
3. Use the same SSID but different channels. If the devices are on the same channel they will be yelling over each other, making your airspace suffer. If they have the same SSID and key then devices can roam between the two devices without explicitly disconnecting from one and choosing to connect to the other.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to access your second router settings while in WDS Bridging:

- Reset router B and while setting up bridging go to **Network** > **Lan settings** > **Enable Second IP**.
- Enable it and enter another IP of your choice and subnet mask. E.g. IP: `192.168.6.1`, subnet mask: `255.255.255.0`.
- Then do your bridging process, at once (first login)
- After both things done you are all set. Now, to log in to your second router setting use the IP address which you entered in second IP.

**Tip**: Sometimes it won't load the login page through second IP.
So, just turn of and on the Wi-Fi and reload the login page immediately.